# how to set line width & color of connection line in draw2d?

Tags: java, draw2d

I am trying to set width and color of connection line in draw2d. 
I found method "setLineWidth()" method but on what I need to call this method. I call this method on input port object but did not work. Plz help me.

Comment: ? - when call you the method? - on which object (port or connection)? your question is not clear for me.

Comment: I am calling it on port object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please post some of your code? This is working for me:

```
    PolylineConnection connection = new PolylineConnection();
    connection.setLineWidth(2);
    connection.setSourceAnchor(new ChannelStartAnchor(this));
    connection.setTargetAnchor(new ChannelEndAnchor(figure));


    Display display = Display.getCurrent();
    final Color connectionColorHoover = display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_RED);
    final Color connectionColor = new Color(display,54,82,111);
    connection.setBackgroundColor(connectionColor);
    connection.setForegroundColor(connectionColor);
```